# css first list item, but not nested ones

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<style>
li {
    font-size: 80%;
}
</style>

<ul>
    <li> level1
    <ul>
        <li> level2
            <ul>                
                <li>level3</li>
            </ul>        
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want all the the text in the three `<li>`'s to be the same but they get smaller, how do I style all of them as `font-size: 80%`?

**Edit**

It would be better not to add classnames because I'm considering using markdown to preprocess the nested bullets (making it difficult to affect the html output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin's answer is probably your best approach, but just to provide an alternative solution:

```
<style>
li {
    font-size: 80%;
}
li li {
    font-size: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a class to style the elements.  This will prevent the `font-size` from getting increasingly smaller.

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li> level1
    <ul>
        <li> level2
            <ul>                
                <li>level3</li>
            </ul>        
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.myList{
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative font-size which means they'll become 80% the size of the parent, so each nested list will be progressively smaller.

Id suggest using a measurement that isn't relative to its parent - set them with `px` or even the `[rem][1]` so they're relative to the root sizes.

Answer (score 0):

An answer that might suit better for the Markdown situation is something like this

```
<style>
.page>ol, .page>ul {
    font-size: 80%;
}
</style>

<div class="page">
<ul>
    ...
</ul>   
</div>
```

Where the angle bracket selects the immediate child-node only